# MySQL logical operation SELECT query

Tags: mysql, select

I have the following query.

```
SELECT 
    f.id, f.food_name, tm.resource_id, tm.tag_id, t.name
FROM 
    tag as t, tagmap as tm
JOIN 
    item as f 
    ON 
    (
    f.id = tm.resource_id AND tm.tag_id = 
        (
        SELECT 
            t.tag_id 
        FROM 
            tag as t 
        WHERE 
            t.name LIKE '%meat%' OR t.name LIKE '%vegan%'
        ) 
    )
GROUP by f.id
```

I believe the error is in line

```
f.id = tm.resource_id AND tm.tag_id =
```

It is looking for a single tag_id and receiving many thus the error: *Error executing the SQL statement*

What is the procedure to receive an array of tag_id 's? I know this statement works for a single ID because if I remove the second WHERE condition the query works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `IN` keyword:

```
...
AND tm.tag_id IN -- Changed  = to IN here
    (
    SELECT 
        t.tag_id 
    FROM 
        tag as t 
    WHERE 
        t.name LIKE '%meat%' OR t.name LIKE '%vegan%'
    ) 
...
```

The basic problem you had was that the select would return multiple rows, and when it did, the statement exploded because `=` can only handle one value.